# MS Office Interop for OS X

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, office-interop, xamarin.mac

I've been searching high and low for information on interop with the Mac versions of Office (specifically, PowerPoint).  I haven't been able to find any documentation on what APIs are available, or even what protocol is used to access them... (something like COM? Apple-native automation APIs? something else entirely?)

It seems like it is possible, though.  Various "PowerPoint remote control" apps exist for Mac that are able to make a running instance of PowerPoint switch slides, and even seem able to extract the presenter notes from each slide.  That's clearly interop of some flavor!

All related  to Microsoft.Office.Interop references  require to have  windows, is there any solution to my problem, or i just have run windows on a virtual machine...

**Update**

So we did some research:

1. First we tried Mono that allows you to build C# in mac, this approach was not successful since the libraries for automation of powerpoint presentation require a windows
2. We tried Apache.poi we were successful creating modifying powerpoint presentation, but this approach is not real time which is not beneficial
3. The third approach and the most logical but limited,(only to move forwards and backwards ) is to simulate the mac commands Keys (arrows)(for forward and backwards) so whenever it's needed we recreate those commands

This three approaches are step forward but do no allow us to draw or modify parts of the presentation in real time, looking for advice.

Thank you in advance