# How can I control a PowerPoint presentation programmatically through Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, office-interop

I realize that there is the Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint namespace, but that is only for Windows. How can I control a PPT on a mac and possibly grab the slide's slide notes as well?

Answer (score 0):

There is Mono, which is an implementation of the .NET library on Linux / macOS. But at the time of writing this, [Mono doesn't support the .NET COM interface.](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/com-interop/)

Comment: Yeah, I came across this information on this post [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533504/ms-office-interop-for-os-x), I don't know how other apps on the app-store manage this.

Slide notes are actually easy to get, but an image of the slide itself is much more difficult.